# How to avoid the alarm triggering when the alarm time is past?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, repeatingalarm

I have scheduled an alarm to trigger on every day 10 AM.

I am setting this alarm at 12 AM Monday.

If the alarm time is past then the alarm will be triggered immediately.

but for my requirement I don't want to trigger immediately. Is fine for me to trigger on next day 10 AM.

**Below is my current code to set Alarm:**

```
Calendar activeModeTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    // activeModeTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(Constants.TIME_ZONE));
    activeModeTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,
            mSharedPrefManager.getActiveStartHourPref());
    activeModeTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE,
            Constants.DEFAULT_ACTIVE_START_MINUTE);
    activeModeTime.set(Calendar.SECOND,
            Constants.ALL_START_END_DEFAULT_SECOND);

    mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            activeModeTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
            getActiveModeAlarmPendingIntent());
```

how do I achieve this.

Comment: Set it for the day after.

Comment: I can set for tuesday.. But next week Monday I need this alarm na... How to do this?

Comment: Simply set the next date.

Answer (score 5):

Check if the time that you've set is in the past and if it is then add 24 hrs to your trigger time.

```
if(activeModeTime < System.currentTimeMillis()){
    activeModeTime += AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY;
}
```

Comment: Is there is parameter is available to set for not to trigger for past time.

Comment: Nope the method `setRepeating()` is not overloaded in `AlarmManager` so there isn't a parameter we can pass for this atm.

Comment: And also API 19 and above the alarm is inexact. I am testing in device 4.4.4. I scheduled an alarm for 10 AM. Now time will be 10.15 AM. Still the alarm is not getting triggered. IS there any specific time of delay?

Comment: It should fire immediately when the time has elapsed but when did that stop working because in the question you've mentioned "If the alarm time is past then the alarm will be triggered immediately. ". One way to ensure the alarm triggers precisely on time is to set a one-time alarm and schedule the next one when you handle the delivery of alarm.

Comment: I can not set one time alarm also. Even that one time set method also inexact from api 19 .

Comment: use `setExact()` Check out the doc ---> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29

Comment: yes I have checked already. But it requires the API 19. So I have to check the API. If less than 19 then I can use the above, If 19 and above then I have to use setExact. But this setExact is also not repeating one.

Comment: So make the logic a little flexible so that when 19 and above is detected you use `setExact()` to tigger an intent and make the `receiver` listening for that event again use `setExact()` to schedule the next alarm after its processing is done (but only if the API > = 19) otherwise use `setRepeating()` and don't make the `receiver` reset manually.

Comment: Is better to have one more method for api 19 and above setExactRepeating. We have setExact Method for one time alarm not for repeating on api version 19 and above.

Comment: yes trpride. I too thought of doing the same. Going to use Set or SetExact. Inside the broadcast receiver I am going to schedule the next alarm.

Comment: Very nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

write interval instead of REPEATING_INTERVAL.
For above example of 10 AM you need to write AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY instead of REPEATING_INTERVAL in below code.

```
if(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()>=calendar.getTimeInMillis()){
   timeInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis() + REPEATING_INTERVAL;
}else { 
   timeInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
}

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis,REPEATING_INTERVAL, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add some explanation to your code.